# Power BI - Show only values > 0 in chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to show only `values > 0` in a chart? On the X - axis I have several fields with a 0 and that's why I want to hide them. So can I set anywhere a minimum value?

Comment: You can add a filter and put some condition like -> myColumn> 0

Comment: Ok thx that works in the Query Editor. Is it possible to add something like a filter in the data view?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-report-add-filter

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Y" axis instead of "X" - It has the effect you may be looking for.

If you want to start at your highest value, enter a 1 for 100% in the Y axis start box and leave the end at auto, and the graph will automatically size from your lowest value greater than zero